# Shiny app returns empty histogram with no values

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following shiny app

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("ABR Dashboard"),

    tabsetPanel(               
      
      tabPanel("Distribution",
               sidebarLayout(
                 selectInput(inputId = "Date", 
                             label = "Select Date", 
                             choices = seq.Date(lubridate::as_date(lubridate::now())-14, 
                                                lubridate::as_date(lubridate::now())-1, 
                                                by = "day")),
                 selectInput(inputId = "Metric",
                             label = "Which Metric",
                             choices = c("ABR_Actuals",
                                         "Abr_Preds",
                                         "Queue",
                                         "Login",
                                         "Tier"))
               ),
               
               mainPanel(
                 plotOutput("distPlot3")
               )
      )
    )
)



server <- function(input, output) {

      output$distPlot3 <- renderPlot({
        
      filtered_data <- reactive({
        dplyr::filter(DT, 
                      DT$MinuteOfDay %in% input$Date & 
                        DT$variable %in% input$Metric)
      })

      #selected_col <- input$Metric
      
      #filtered_data = dplyr::filter(DT, MinuteOfDay %in% input$Date)

      ggplot(filtered_data(),
             aes(x = variable)) +
             geom_histogram()
      
})


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This produces an app but the histogram is empty.

Any ideas what is wrong?

[image]

Data looks like this (DT)

[image]

Comment: I can't find DT. Where is DT?

Comment: DT is just an RDS file with a data frame that I am using to mock this up with

Answer (score 1):

Try this :
The code is working, I changed the `geom_histogram()` to `geom_bar()`. I think the main issue is here:

```
choices = seq.Date(lubridate::as_date(lubridate::now())-14,                                                 lubridate::as_date(lubridate::now())-1,                                                 by = "day")),`
```

If you change the choices like I did, and there is data for this date then `geom_bar()` is displayed: Changes are indicated in the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)
library(lubridate)

# example dataset
set.seed(123)  
DT <- data.frame(
  MinuteOfDay = seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), by = "day", length.out = 100),
  variable = sample(c("ABR_Actuals", "Abr_Preds", "Queue", "Login", "Tier"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  value = rnorm(100)  
)

DT$MinuteOfDay <- as.Date(DT$MinuteOfDay)


library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("ABR Dashboard"),
  
  tabsetPanel(               
    
    tabPanel("Distribution",
             sidebarLayout(
               selectInput(inputId = "Date", 
                           label = "Select Date", 
                           choices = DT$MinuteOfDay), # <- changed here the time span 
               selectInput(inputId = "Metric",
                           label = "Which Metric",
                           choices = unique(DT$variable)) # <- changed here
             ),
             
             mainPanel(
               plotOutput("distPlot3")
             )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$distPlot3 <- renderPlot({
    
    filtered_data <- reactive({
      dplyr::filter(DT, 
                    DT$MinuteOfDay %in% input$Date & 
                      DT$variable %in% input$Metric)
    })
    

    ggplot(filtered_data(), aes(x = variable)) +
      geom_bar()  # <- changed here to geom_bar
  })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]